# How do I get current weather conditions using the Yahoo Weather API and the Lat and Longitude of my iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, api, yahoo, weather

I have searched google and stackoverflow many times, but I can't seem to find the answer. I am needing to get the current weather for my location using the yahoo api. Please don't suggest other apis as this is for work and I can't use anything else. I am getting the lat and long of the device, but I can't seem to find the proper URL for the request. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, if providing code, please do so in objective-c/iOS. I have looked through the documentation for the api, but I am not seeing what I need. I need to get the woeid so that I can then request the weather condition.

Thanks!

Comment: That api call is no longer valid. I believe that quite recently yahoo made some api changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the web I found that this URL:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%2237.416275%2C-122.025092%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22
```

give you a JSON with the information you are looking for

[image]

you will have to replace the coordinates `37.416275` and `-122.025092` with your own values, I guest it is possible to get the response in JSON format to.

**EDIT**

In this [site](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/free_YQL.html) you can find more information.

Comment: but it gives info for a certain time.. like temp. in morning not the current conditions